How to deploy vite in cyclic?
I am new to deploying websites. I have a website that works on my local but I am having trouble while deploying it.
My scripts:
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "backend": "cd backend && node server.js",
    "starter": "concurrently \"npm run dev\" \"npm run backend\"",
    "start": "npm run dev & npm run backend"
  },

the log in cyclic:

Connected to MongoDB
Server listening on port  4000
 sh: vite: command not found
 / GET

